# Creating a pop-up-menu window with JavaScript & CSS

Tags: javascript, css, jsx

I try to create a small pop-up-menu window with CSS und JavaScript. Unfortunately the most instructions that I could find by using Google are solutions which uses CSS, JS AND HTML, but Im searching for a solution that only uses CSS & JavaScript.

I think it has definetely to use „onclick“. By clicking a small pop-up-menu that includes 2 buttons it should offer 2 options by these 2 buttons. Each button should open a new different greater pop-up-menu window. Code around is quite ready and works. So the "only" thing I have to do is to build in is that tiny menu between.

This is the Code where it has to be implement:

```
if (!this.props.dataHandler.userData.isAdmin() && this.props.action === 'activeDevices') {
    tableBody.push(
        <tr
            id={primaryKeyValue}
            onClick={this.renderModal.bind(this, 'reserve', primaryKeyValue)}
            key={primaryKeyValue}
        >
            {children}
            <span className="table-img" id={primaryKeyValue + '_IMG'}></span>
        </tr>
    );
} 
else {
    tableBody.push(
        <tr id={primaryKeyValue} onClick={this.renderModal.bind(this, 'edit', primaryKeyValue)} key={primaryKeyValue}>
            {children}
            <span className="table-img" id={primaryKeyValue + '_IMG'}></span>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

I thought I could use an if/else fork that opens the tiny menu and the following greater menu. And in the onclick-Statement which opens the following greater menu I thought to implement an inner onclick that pops up the tiny menu before. Is this possible? Am I thinking the right way? Or how should I do it the best way?

Another idee would be to build no tiny menu between but choose the greater following menus by clicking the left or the right mouse button. This should be a bit easier?

Comment: Can you create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your code so that we can test it out and try and give you some help?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: 1. Even with a solution that uses javascript and css, you can always use the `document.createElement('element_tag_name')` method, followed by an `append()` to create new html elements dyncamically, thus allowing you to use a Javascript, css, and html solution. 2. Why not use something like bootstrap or some other library that has pop up menus?

Comment: I forgot to tell that the buttons are already created in the function createButtons(): "var usrMenu = <input key=...". They work. So I just have to integrate them. But I dont know how and how I can get a white window/modal arround the 2 buttons. The 2 buttons should just link to this "onClick={this.renderModal.bind(this, 'edit', primaryKeyValue)}". The entire code is just too much and has got too many make files to present it.

Comment: So the 2 buttons are already created and work. I just have to tell the code, that if I click on a list element it should open the mini menu with the 2 created buttons/options "reserve" and "edit". And by clicking those, it should open the 2 different greater menus. Btw the 2 different greater menus which should open by clicking are ready too and work fine. It has to be very simple, but all I have tried right now, does not work. I think it is nothing more than an interlinked code line, like if you click this button than... and by clicking this open the other menu.

Answer (score 0):

So I definitely have to use React. Is it correct that I have to initialize the buttons with "var", than use them in a function and assigning the window/menu I want to open with it and additionally building a React command? Three things to do? But can I easily integrate them all in the affected funktion or is it more complex. And how could I implement the whole thing? All my efforts still dont work.

So in the end I just have to create a 2 buttons option around two different menus which open by clicking the first or the second button.

Edit:
No one :(? Unfortunately I have made no headway since one week in this point :(.